# Customizing <vaadin-button> when in focus

Tags: css, vaadin, customization, vaadin-flow, theming

I'd like to create a customized Lumo theme in Vaadin 14.6, where the buttons (`<vaadin-button>`) show a double border (css: `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 3px var(--some-custom-background-color);`) when focussed.
While custom styles for other `<vaadin-button>` pseudo selectors, such as `:hover`, `:active`, etc. work well, I cannot find a way to customize the `:focus` appearance.

Comment: Show your efforts, so that we can achieve your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it is actually Firefox which is not showing the `:focus` related css. Chrome and Safari display the style as desired.

For the sake of completeness, this is the related css, which goes into 'vaadin-button.css' in the 'themes/components' folder of the application:

```
:host([theme~="primary"]:focus) {
    height: calc(var(--my-button-size) - 6px);
    border-radius: 1px;
    background-color: var(--my-button-primary-background-color-focus);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 3px var(--my-button-primary-background-color);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Focus styles need to be customized using the `focused` and `focus-ring` state attributes, which are applied on the host element.

The `focused` attribute is applied the button is focused either with a mouse/pointer or keyboard, while `focus-ring` is only applied when it’s focused with the keyboard (corresponds to the native `:focus-visible` pseudo class).

```css
:host([focused]) {
  ...
}

:host([focus-ring]) {
  ...
}
```